# page-break-before fails in FF Chrome and Safari pc

Tags: html, css, printing

See this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/GEQxj/1/

I have tried several suggestions like

```
float:none; 
overflow:visible; 
display:block;
break-before: always;
```

What i want to accomplish - is the table with the child class to be to be printed in a landscape fashion.  The rotation works across all browsers.  However the page-break-before only works in ie8 at the moment.  Does not work in latest versions of FF Chrome and Safari.

This page is generated from another page for the sole purpose of being printed so no need for @media print.

Comment: were you ever able to find a solution to this? I am currently trying to figure out why Chrome does not seem to adhere to page-break-before when printing in landscape mode.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this:

```
margin-top:280px;
margin-left:-230px;
```

It looks good in chrome and firefox http://jsfiddle.net/GEQxj/23/
You can target just webkit browsers and firefox with this:

```
 @media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
 /* Safari and Chrome CSS here */
 }

 @-moz-document url-prefix() {
 /* Firefox CSS here */
 }
```